# Activate Linux GUI only for a specific application Lubuntu 21.10

Tags: linux, bash, gui, lubuntu, lxde

I need to setup a linux client(OS:Lubuntu 21.10) witch launch only a web page on Chromium browser always fixed all the time 24/24. It's possibile for you to use the client in CLI mode and start LXDE/LXQT (Lubuntu GUI) only for chromium?
All is ok with LXDE booted up, but because I want to optimize HW resources I've think about to a GUI "on-demand" ...It's possible? Too difficult? Thanks to all (sorry for my english)

Alessandro

Comment: Just install an X environment on the machine and have the user launch it from a terminal locally or SSH in with an X environment and do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult for me to understand, what exactly do you want. If understand correctly, you would like to start XWindows with chromium and nothing else.

You can start XWindows with xinit. Then put the programs to launch in ~/.xinitrc. In your case, for chromium it would be

```
chromium --kiosk https://yoursite/
```

If you want your computer to show that for 24/7, you would also like to disable screensaver, right?

```
/usr/bin/xset s noblank
/usr/bin/xset s off
/usr/bin/xset dpms 0 0 0
/usr/bin/xset -dpms
```

Here is a sample of .xinitrc

```
/usr/bin/xset s noblank
/usr/bin/xset s off
/usr/bin/xset dpms 0 0 0
/usr/bin/xset -dpms
xfwm4 --daemon &
xfce4-panel &
chromium --kiosk https://yoursite/ &
xfdesktop
```

The point is that only the last program does not exit. It if exists, the XWindows will close.

Comment: Yes, correct. I want to start the client in CLI mode, and only activate the lxde GUI for chromium session for 24/7.